# Android File Chooser on Simulator

Tags: android, emulation, android-afilechooser

I have a problem when I am unable to choose the required file in android select file dialog on emulator. I am able to see the file but the selection is disabled as shown in screen capture below. This problem comes only with emulator and not with real devices.

[image]

Following is the code that I have written for displaying file select dialog.

```
findViewById(R.id.browse).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("file/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

While I was not able to solve it with android native file chooser that comes in emulator. I could successfully use ES file explorer to solve this problem.